# Python Django - Passing in multiple parameters to Factory during testing

Tags: python, django, testing, tuples, factory

I'm currently working on a practice social media app. In this app, current users can invite their friends by email to join the app (specifically, joining a 'channel' of the app, like Discord). For this project, I'm working on functionality where a user will get an error if they try to invite someone who is already in the app (meaning people who are already in the app's database). I'm working on unit tests that ensures the error messages pop up when users are detected as already existing.

I managed to get my first scenario working, but I'm a bit stumped for the second one.

Here is a file that is central to both tests.

factories.py

```
class ChannelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory)
 class Meta:
  model = Channel
  id = int
  name = str

class CurrentUserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory)
 class Meta:
  model = CurrentUser
  user_email = user_email
  channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)
```

Scenario #1 (currently working) - one new user is invited to join the app but already exists in the app's database

test_forms.py

```
from tests.factories import ChannelFactory, CurrentUserFactory

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_that_current_user_cannot_be_reinvited(email, error_message):
"""user that is already in the specific channel cannot be reinvited"""

email = "user@test.com"
error_message = "user@test.com already exists in this channel"

# I am not specifying the channel name because the factory object is supposed to generate it automatically
current_user = CurrentUserFactory(user_email='user@test.com')

invite_form = forms.UserRequestForm({"email":email, channel=current_user.channel)

assert not invite_form is valid()
assert invite_form.errors["email"][0] = error_message
```

Result: Test passes!

However, the test passes mainly because there's only one user being tested.

So now, my task is to create a test to see what happens if several people are invited at once. The app allows for a comma separated string to be entered, so theoretically up to ten emails can be invited at a time.

Scenario #2 - two new users are invited to the same channel and both exist in the app's database. Here's where I'm running into issues because I need to somehow make sure the CurrentUsers are generated into the same channel.

```
from tests.factories import CurrentUserFactory
    
@pytest.mark.django_db
def tests_that_multiple_current_users_cannot_be_reinvited(emails, error_message):
"""users that are already in the specific channel cannot be reinvited"""

emails = ["user@test.com", "user2@test.com"]
error_message = "The following users already exist in this channel: user@test.com, user2@test.com"

#here, I attempt to "force" a Channel instance
channel = Channel(id="5", name="Hometown Friends")

current_users = [
(CurrentUserFactory(user_email='user@test.com', channel=channel)),
(CurrentUserFactory(user_email='user2@test.com', channel=channel)),
]

invite_form = forms.UserRequestForm({"email":emails, "channel":current_users.channel})

assert not invite_form is valid()
assert invite_form.errors["email"][0] = error_message
```

When I try running the test:

```
E AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

I'm wondering if I can easily solve this by trying to work with the tuple, or if there's a much easier method that I'm somehow not seeing. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is another way to store some objects together, like list or array.

You are trying to get the attribute 'channel' from a tuple here:

```
invite_form = forms.UserRequestForm({"email":emails, "channel":current_users.channel})
```

Since you have put two objects in a tuple, you need to give python exact address of the object you want to get the attribute from.

Try this instead:

```
invite_form_1 = forms.UserRequestForm({"email":emails[0], "channel":current_users[0].channel})
invite_form_2 = forms.UserRequestForm({"email":emails[1], "channel":current_users[1].channel})
```

Now you are telling python to look at the first object in tuple current_users and get its attribute 'channel', and then in second line you look at the second object in that tuple.

Obviously, in this case you also have to assert both forms separately.

If you want to have a test for x number of forms you can also use a loop:

```
invite_forms = []

for i in x:
    invite_forms.append(
    forms.UserRequestForm({"email":emails[i], "channel":current_users[i].channel}))
```

*(Just make sure emails and current_users have enough objects!)*

Here you add x UserRequestForm objects into the invite_forms tuple/list.

Again, this would require you to also iterate through the assertions.